# mtext() in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering what's wrong with `mtext()` that I can't get the number `G` correctly show above my plot?

**Here is my R code:**

```
G <- .3333 ## but G can be anything as it comes from a function

curve(dnorm(x),-3,3)
mtext(expression(paste("Medium: ",bold('CT'[12])," = ", round(G,2))),line=3)
```

Comment: round returns a numeric which is 0.3333. You need the value as a character or compose it. Can't you just enter:
curve(dnorm(x),-3,3)
mtext(expression(paste("Medium: ",bold('CT'[12])," = ", ".3333")),line=3) instead?

Comment: David, in fact, .3333 comes from a function, so it can vary!

Comment: Ok seems that I got lost there, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bquote` and `.()` (this is used to include variables in an expression) for this:

```
G <- 0.3333
curve(dnorm(x),-3,3)
mtext(bquote(paste("Medium: ",bold('CT'[12])," = ", .(round(G,3)))),line=3)
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: You are very welcome, glad I could help. This sounds like a separate question that someone could benefit from. Would you mind posting that as a new question so that we keep questions as unique entities?